# combine two sans fonts for xelatex/lualatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

I'm still finding my way around latex, so forgive me is this is an obvious question...

I have two sans serif ttf fonts available at my workplace that I want to use in xelatex or lualatex.  The serif (Caslon) font works well and regular, italic, bold and bold-italic are all available.

On my Windows system the two sans fonts are shown as "KingsBureauGrot FiveOne" (which consists of a light and a light italic versions) and "KingsBureauGrot Three Seven" (which consists of a Bold and a Bold Italic versions).

My question is, how can I combine these two fonts into one set so I have regular (light), italic (light italic), bold and bold-italic and they all behave as a single font family?

I have see this sort of approach before e.g.

```
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text,
 BoldFont={HelveticaNeue-Bold}, BoldItalic={HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic},
 ItalicFont={HelveticaNeue-LightItalic}]{HelveticaNeue-Light}
```

but that only deals with one font family (HelveticaNeue-Light in this case).

Hope that is sufficiently clear!

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify any font you like for any of the variants: they don't need to be from the same family.  So for example, you could produce the following awful combination:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text,
 BoldFont={DejaVu Sans Condensed Bold},
 BoldItalicFont={Florencesans SC Cond Bold Italic},
 ItalicFont={Gill Sans Light Italic}]{Helvetica}

\begin{document}
\sffamily This is in Helvetica.

\textbf{This is in DejaVu Sans}

\emph{\textbf{This is in Florence Sans}}

\emph{This is in Gill Sans Light Italic}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I hadn't realised this was possible, thanks.  I was throw by the {Helvetica} at the end thinking all fonts had to be from that family...