# How can I set footnotes to different font and size to main text?

Tags: fonts, footnotes, fontsize, fontspec

I have to prepare a document with the following criteria - 1.5 spacing, text in Times New Roman, Size 12 (with footnotes throughout in Calibri, Size 10). Since I'm using luaLaTeX to get the fonts I'm not sure if the [change font of footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4779/54029) answers apply.
In my MWE I am able to get the times font and have the 1.5 line spacing but how can I set the footnote font to size 10 and Calibri?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{times}
%\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}
\usepackage [autostyle=once,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage [UKenglish,american,british]{babel}
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, includeall=false,]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

This is test.\footnote{Test footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news: The method mentioned in the link you've provided is fully applicable to your document as well. :-)

By the way, since your main document font size is `12pt`, `\footnotesize` works out to be `10pt` -- exactly what you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % or: 'XITS', which is a Times Roman clone
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}
\usepackage [autostyle=once,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage [UKenglish,american,british]{babel}
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, includeall=false,]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
%\onehalfspacing
\setstretch{1.5}

%% See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4781/5001 for the following code:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\footnotesize\sffamily}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\textheight{3cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}
This is test.\footnote{Test footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Given the question and the answer, isn't that a duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B - It would appear (to me at least) that there was a second issue in the new posting: How to enable a particular sans-serif font? I handled this issue in my answer by changing `\setmainfont{Calibri}` to `\setsansfont{Calibri}`. Admittedly, not a particularly difficult thing to do...

Comment: I think we could close more questions as duplicates. But those tiny little things making a question unique ... Honestly, it bothers me a bit.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Has this been raised/discussed/decided on Meta?

Comment: Discussed on meta. Have a look at my answer to that Duplicate automation finding magical  software from a few days ago.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Ah, it's been a few days since I last checked in on Meta. Let me take a look now...

Comment: I don't mind marking my question as a dup. Also I am getting the following warning the `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/Calibri(0)/m/it' undefined (Font) using `EU2/Calibri(0)/m/n' instead on input line 40.` I think this is effecting my footnotes as there is not italitc text for book titles etc when citing from bib file. While using Linux I do have the calibri files installed. Don't know if these issues are enough to not make as a dup @Johannes_B

Comment: @gman How to get Calibri Italic is a completely different question and unrelated to footnotes, or bibliographies.

Comment: @gman - Which operating system is on your computer, and which TeX distribution do you employ? (Depending on the OS, only the upright shape but not the italic shape of Calibri may be available.) FWIW, Calibri Italic is installed on my MacOS Sierra/MacTeX2016 system.)

Comment: I was able to sort it out by adapting my code to `\setsansfont[BoldFont={CalibriBold}, BoldItalic={CalibriBoldItalic},
 ItalicFont={CalibriItalic}]{Calibri}` from [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55969/54029)  Thanks @mico and @johannes_B for the help and comments. I mark this question as dup.

Answer (score 1):

Following a crude hack. Patching the font change directly into the footnotetext might be cleaner.

[image: gmanFontFootnotes]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}
\usepackage [autostyle=once,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage [UKenglish,american,british]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Chorus}#1}}
\begin{document}

This is test.\footnote{Test footnote.}

\end{document}
```